# Trouble with keeping SAS from showing charts

Tags: sas

When I use the code

```
proc anova data="/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/swiss.sas7bdat";
 title "All groups";
 class group;
 model creat_68=group;
 means group / bon;
 means group / tukey;
 means group / scheffe;
run;
```

I have three distribution charts printed, one for each bon, tukey, and scheffe. How can I prevent these from showing?

Comment: it's a coding question

Comment: add the line ods graphics off;  before the anova as another alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add PLOTS  = NONE;  to the PROC ANOVA statement.  (That's a good general rule for many statistical SAS PROCs).

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment. OTOH, I recognize that this is a programming Q, & this may be all there is to say. I'm migrating this thread to [SO].